# Mark mode in Terminal without mouse

Tags: linux, unix, command-line-interface

Is it possible to enter mark mode(to mark text in Linux terminal) without mouse. In CMD you can ,<kbd>alt+space+e+k</kbd>. Can it be done natively without 3th party programs?

Comment: What terminal? The character mode console or one of the plethora of X terminal applications?

Comment: For example terminal in ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of your terminal you can enable vi mode for you shell, both bash and zsh support this.

Answer (score 0):

A quick one (without installing third party programs) would be to `set -o vi` in your shell to enable vi and use the [shortcuts](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/806-7612/6jgfmsvqf/index.html#:%7E:text=Press%20w%20(%E2%80%9Cword%E2%80%9D),character%20of%20the%20current%20word.)

If you don't like it you can always come back to emacs: `set -o emacs`